# AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'setup_data_loader.<locals>.seed_worker'

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, pickle

I am trying to reproduce the paper: [Large Language Models are Zero Shot Reasoners](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/large-language-models-are-zero-shot-reasoners)
When running `main.py`, it outputs following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\GitHub project\zero_shot_cot\main.py", line 217, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 120, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 130, in _main
    main()
  File "D:\GitHub project\zero_shot_cot\main.py", line 36, in main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    for i, data in enumerate(dataloader):

EOFError: Ran out of input
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 441, in __iter__
    return self._get_iterator()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 388, in _get_iterator
    return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 1042, in __init__
    w.start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 94, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'setup_data_loader.<locals>.seed_worker'
```

from the error, I think the function `setup_data_loader` in `utils.py` may have some problems,especially function `seed_worker`. But I have no idea about how to solve.

[all code](https://github.com/kojima-takeshi188/zero_shot_cot#large-language-models-are-zero-shot-reasoners)
Following code are the function `setup_data_loader`:

```py
def setup_data_loader(args):

    # fix randomness of dataloader to ensure reproducibility
    # https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html
    fix_seed(args.random_seed)
    worker_seed = torch.initial_seed() % 2**32
    print("worker_seed : {}".format(worker_seed))
    def seed_worker(worker_id):
        np.random.seed(worker_seed)
        random.seed(worker_seed)
    g = torch.Generator()
    g.manual_seed(worker_seed)
    
    dataloader_num_workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    dataloader_num_workers = min(dataloader_num_workers, args.max_num_worker)
    print("dataloader_num_workers: " + str(dataloader_num_workers))
    
    dataset = MyDataset(args)
    
    dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset,
                  shuffle=True,
                  batch_size=args.minibatch_size,
                  drop_last=False,
                  num_workers=dataloader_num_workers,
                  worker_init_fn=seed_worker,
                  generator=g,
                  pin_memory=True)

    return dataloader
```